Creating LaTeX Macros to Generate Tables from Predefined Variables
I've been struggling for the past two days to create macros for populating a thesis title page, as I'm planning to share it as a template with my colleagues. As you all know, thesis title pages have the same structure, and the only changes are the names of the authors, supervisors, and thesis committee members.
My idea is to create variables (or whatever they are called in LaTeX jargon) \authors, \supervisors, and \thesisCommittee, which will respectively hold the first and last names of the authors, supervisors, and thesis committee members.
Here is an example of what the variables should look like (you can suggest any other data structure you find suitable for this use case; this format is not a requirement):
\newcommand{\authors}{
    {firstName1, lastName1},
    {firstName2, lastName2},
    {firstName3, lastName3}
}

\newcommand{\supervisors}{
    {firstName1, lastName1},
    {firstName2, lastName2},
    {firstName3, lastName3}
}

\newcommand{\thesisCommittee}{
    {firstName1, lastName1, institute1, role1},
    {firstName2, lastName2, institute2, role2},
    {firstName3, lastName3, institute3, role3}
}

The idea is that any student using this template can simply fill these variables with the corresponding attributes and then use the following macros to print the corresponding information:
\printAuthors
\printSupervisors
\printThesisCommittee

The definitions of these macros will not be visible to the user, as I am planning to store them in a .sty file, which can then be imported into the main .tex file. The user will only need to edit the definitions of the variables \authors, \supervisors, and \thesisCommittee in the main file.
I've spent a lot of time searching for related questions on the internet, but I always end up finding solutions that only partially match my requirements, which I can't adapt to suit my needs. I don't have solid LaTeX capabilities, especially when the solution uses expl3. Here are some of the answers I found but couldn't adapt:
For \printAuthors and \printSupervisors, I found this solution.
\documentclass{report}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_authors_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_authors_clist { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAuthors}{}
 {
  \clist_if_empty:NF \g_authors_clist
   {
    \begin{tabular}{ @{} l l @{} }
    Authors: & \clist_use:Nn \g_authors_clist { \\ & }
    \end{tabular}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\authors{Name 1, Name 2}
\printAuthors

\end{document}


As you can see, I can only provide the whole name of an author, not separate the first and last names (I chose to separate them because I might want to apply some formatting to the last or first name, for example, making it bold and UPPERCASE). I also want to modify the content of the first cell (i.e. dynamically change the word Authors). I want the macro to allow the user to provide two forms for it (one for plural and one for singular) and decide automatically which form to use based on the number of authors and supervisors.
On the other hand for the maco \printThesisCommitee i have found this solution (and again i didn't succed in adapting it):
\documentclass{report}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printThesisCommittee}{m}
 {
  \committee_main:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__committee_cols_seq
\tl_new:N \l__committee_body_tl
\int_new:N \l__committee_rows_int

\keys_define:nn { key/val }
 {
  unknown .code:n = { \__committee_add:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \committee_main:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__committee_cols_seq
  \tl_clear:N \l__committee_body_tl
  \int_zero:N \l__committee_rows_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \__committee_add_row:n { ##1 }
   }
%   \tl_put_left:Nx \l__committee_body_tl
%    { & \seq_use:Nn \l__committee_cols_seq { & } \exp_not:n { \\ \hline } }
  \begin{tabular}{ |c*{ \seq_count:N \l__committee_cols_seq } { |c }| }
  \tl_use:N \l__committee_body_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__committee_add_row:n
 {
  \int_incr:N \l__committee_rows_int
%   \tl_put_right:Nx \l__committee_body_tl
%    {
%     \int_to_Alph:n { \l__committee_rows_int }
%    }
  \keys_set:nn { key/val } { #1 }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__committee_body_tl { \\ }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__committee_add:n
 {
  \seq_if_in:NxF \l__committee_cols_seq { \l_keys_key_tl }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__committee_cols_seq { \l_keys_key_tl }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__committee_body_tl { & #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printThesisCommittee{
    {firstName=name1, lastName=name1, institute=inst1, role=role1},
    {firstName=name2, lastName=name2, institute=inst2, role=role2},
    {firstName=name3, lastName=name3, institute=ins31, role=role3}
}

\end{document}


Additionally, I prefer using the tblr environment from the tabularray package instead of the tabular environment, as it gives me the ability to set the width of the generated table and use the X[c,m] option for adjusting the width and the allignment of each column.
To sum up, here's how I envision the title page:

Any suggestions or improvements are welcome.
Thank you in advance!!
Update
I have been trying to implement that macro, and here is what I came up with, (still not what I'm expecting):
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define the variables
\clist_new:N \g_authors_clist
\clist_new:N \g_supervisors_clist
\clist_new:N \g_thesis_committee_clist

% Define the macros
\NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_authors_clist { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\supervisors}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_supervisors_clist { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\thesisCommittee}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_thesis_committee_clist { #1 }
 }

% Macro to print authors
\NewDocumentCommand{\printAuthors}{}
 {
  \clist_if_empty:NF \g_authors_clist
   {
    \begin{tblr}{|r|l|}
    \hline
    \ifnum \clist_count:N \g_authors_clist > 1
      Authors
    \else
      Author
    \fi & 
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_authors_clist { ##1 \\ }
    \end{tblr}
   }
 }

% Macro to print supervisors
\NewDocumentCommand{\printSupervisors}{}
 {
  \clist_if_empty:NF \g_supervisors_clist
   {
    \begin{tblr}{|r|l|}
    \hline
    \ifnum \clist_count:N \g_supervisors_clist > 1
      Supervisors
    \else
      Supervisor
    \fi & 
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_supervisors_clist { ##1 \\ }
    \end{tblr}
   }
 }

% Macro to print thesis committee
\NewDocumentCommand{\printThesisCommittee}{}
 {
  \clist_if_empty:NF \g_thesis_committee_clist
   {
    \begin{tblr}{|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_thesis_committee_clist { ##1 \\ }
    \end{tblr}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% Define the variables
\authors{
    {firstName1, lastName1},
    {firstName2, lastName2},
    {firstName3, lastName3}
}

\supervisors{
    {firstName1, lastName1}
}

\thesisCommittee{
    {firstName1, lastName1, institute1, role1},
    {firstName2, lastName2, institute2, role2},
    {firstName3, lastName3, institute3, role3}
}

% Print the tables
\printAuthors

\bigskip

\printSupervisors

\bigskip

\printThesisCommittee

\end{document}



\documentclass{report}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Define the variables
\clist_new:N \g_authors_clist
\clist_new:N \g_supervisors_clist
\clist_new:N \g_thesis_committee_clist

% Define the macros
\NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{m}
{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_authors_clist { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\supervisors}{m}
{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_supervisors_clist { #1 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\thesisCommittee}{m}
{
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_thesis_committee_clist { #1 }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \formatNames:n #1
{
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eF {##1}{
      &
      \seq_clear_new:N \l__tempa_seq
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__tempa_seq { , } { ##1 }
      \tl_if_blank:eTF {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 1 }}
      {
        \tl_if_blank:eF {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}{{\bfseries\tl_trim_spaces:n {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}}}
      }
      {
        {\tl_trim_spaces:n {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 1 }}} \tl_if_blank:eF {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}{{\c_space_token\bfseries\tl_trim_spaces:n {\seq_item:Nn \l__tempa_seq { 2 }}}}
      }
    \\
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printAuthors}{}
{
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Author
  \int_compare:nNnT {\clist_count:N \g_authors_clist} > 1 { s }
  \formatNames:n \g_authors_clist
\end{tabular}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printSupervisors}{}
{
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Supervisor
  \int_compare:nNnT {\clist_count:N \g_supervisors_clist} > 1 { s }
  \formatNames:n \g_supervisors_clist
\end{tabular}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \formatCommittee:n #1
{
  \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eF {##1}{
      \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
      \clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist
      \clist_gset:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { ##1 }
      \clist_log:N \l_tmpa_clist
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { \tl_trim_spaces:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 }} ~ {\bfseries\tl_trim_spaces:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 2 }}} }
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { Professor ~ at ~ \tl_trim_spaces:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 3 }} }
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { \tl_trim_spaces:n {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 4 }} }
      \clist_log:N \l_tmpb_clist
      \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { & } \\
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printThesisCommittee}{}
{
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \formatCommittee:n \g_thesis_committee_clist
  \end{tabular}
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\authors{%
  {Prénom1, Nom1},
  {Prénom2},
  {, Nom3}
}

\supervisors{
  {firstName1, lastName1},
  {,Nom}
}

\thesisCommittee{
  {firstNAME1, lastName1, institute1, role1},
  {firstNAME2, lastName2, institute2, role2},
  {firstNAME3, lastName3, institute3, role3}
}

\begin{document}
  \printAuthors{}
  
  \printSupervisors{}
  
  \printThesisCommittee{}
\end{document}

produces


Your answer was incredibly helpful. Merci infiniment, professeur :-)
Do you have any idea how to switch from using the tabular environment to the tblr environment from the tabularray package? as it offers more flexibility in adjusting columns.
When I tried to make the change in my code, the compiler raised an error saying: "Package tabularray: Table width is too small, need 351pt more!"
